# Div Layout: static left column width , strechacle right column width

Tags: css, html

%19 Left Section Width, %80 Content width:

[image]

But i want to fix left section to 200px and content section is the rest of viewable area's width.

How can i do this with CSS?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TWO-COLUMN LIQUID LAYOUT WITH FLOATING BOXES</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        div
        {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        #header
        {
            background: #0f0;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #leftcol
        {
            background: #f00;
            float: left;
            width:19%;
            /* max-width: 200px; */ 
            height: 500px;
        }
        #content
        {
            background: #fff;
            float: left;
            width: 80%;
            height: 500px;
        }
        #footer
        {
            background: #0f0;
            clear: both;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        Header Section</div>
    <div id="leftcol">
        Left Section</div>
    <div id="content">
        Content Section</div>
    <div id="footer">
        Footer Section</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's plenty of ready made templates that would work here, take a look at these for example:

- http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-liquid-layout-21-fixed-fluid/
- http://bonrouge.com/2c-hf-fluid.php

Answer (score 1):

Take a look: http://www.brunildo.org/test/lf100r.html